# Ionic, Phonegap - iframes and youtube videos no longer show up

Tags: angularjs, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

for some reason iframes no longer show up when i use the phonegap app. When i try to run older versions of my app where iframes did work, they no longer work.

phonegap version : 5.3.6,

cordova version : 6.0.0,

ionic version : 1.7.14

does anyone no why this is happening?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: not really a solution, i found out that the problem is with the phonegap mobile app and not my code. if you run your app using the mobile app ionic view then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the problem is with phonegaps latest mobile app version because it works when i run my app on a real device and in the ionic view mobile app